# how to make ScrollViewer of Listbox to scroll to Top every time I Load it in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollviewer

I have a Listbox that contains Images as items. we can select the image and it will show the image in image viewer . Now the issue is  when ever I load it the scrollViewer is moving to previously selected item in Listbox instead of first item. what i need to do to  make scrollViewer of Listbox should be on top every time I load?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `ListBox.ScrollIntoView` to scroll a specific item into view:

```
if (listBox.Items.Count > 0)
{
  object firstItem = listBox.Items[0];
  listBox.ScrollIntoView(firstItem);
}
```

Comment: How can we access the listbox data in viewmodel because we can only use them xaml.cs file and I need to handle from Viewmodel

Comment: No, this is never the resposibility of the view model. The view model is only allowed to select the data models, but it has no knowlegde of a scroll viewer or visual presentation of the data models in general. Your original question is very broad and misses  key details, that's why I can only give you this broad answer - broad questions can only get broad answers. You basically have to find a view event and handle it (and execute the above code). What ever event is suitable for you (e.g. `ListBox.SelectionChanged` or `Image.Loaded` - I can't tell)